# Cauchy Product of two simple geometric series

Tags: geometric-series, cauchy-product

I want to calculate the cauchy product of two simple geometric series:

$$\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1/2)^n \right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1/5)^n \right) = 5/2
$$
[Wolfram Alpha result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+%281%2F2%29%5En+from+n%3D0+to+infinity+*+sum+of+%281%2F5%29%5En+from+n%3D0+to+infinity&lk=4&num=1)

According to Wolfram Alpha and finding not the right answer, my calculation is supposed to be wrong:
$$\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1/2)^n \right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1/5)^n \right) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n 1/(2^n5^{n-k})
$$
[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+%28sum+of+1%2F%282%5En*5%5E%28n-k%29%29+from+k%3D0+to+n%29+from+n%3D0+to+infinity)

Can somebody give me a hint, why this is the wrong equatation?

Comment: your sum only includes terms in which the exponent acting on the $5$ is less than or equal to the exponent acting on the $2$

Comment: @WW1 So what does it mean? I'm just trying to follow the formula:
$$
\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n \right) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n a_nb_{n-k})
$$

Comment: That formula is incorrect for the same reason. Surely you can see that the term $a_1 b_2$ will appear on the left but not on the right

Comment: Cauchy's product formula is ...

$$     \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n \right) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n a_kb_{n-k} $$

notice that $a_n$ is replaced by $a_k$

Comment: Thank you very much! That mistake cost me hours...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general ...

$$\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n \right) = \\\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n a_nb_{n-k}+ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{n-k}b_{n}$$

Where the first sum adds terms $a_ib_j$ with $i\ge j$ and the second adds terms $i<j$

A more symmetrical form ( and the one is used to do your calculation ) is ...

$$\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n \right) = \\\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n a_nb_{n-k}+ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_{n-k}b_{n} - \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n b_n
\\= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n ( a_nb_{n-k}+a_{n-k}b_n)- \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n b_n$$

where the last term is correcting for double counting the $i=j$ case

in your case you can verify that ...

$$\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1/2)^n \right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1/5)^n \right) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n 1/(2^n5^{n-k}) + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n 1/(2^{n-k}5^{n}) - \sum_{n=0}^\infty 1/(2^n5^{n}) =\frac 52$$

Comment: *All* your formulas are wrong. E.g. the first one must be replaced by
$$\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n \right) =\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{\frac n2\le k\le n}a_kb_{n-k}+ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{\frac n2<k\le n}a_{n-k}b_k.$$

Answer (score 0):

In general...
$$\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty b_j\right) =\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^na_kb_{n-k}\right)$$
(for more details about convergence conditions, see [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product)).

In the case of two convergent geometric series like yours, with $\alpha,\beta,0$ distinct (in your case: $\alpha=\frac12,\beta=\frac15$), you can check that...
$$\begin{align}\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\alpha^k\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty\beta^j\right)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\alpha^k\beta^{n-k}\right)\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\beta^n\left(\sum_{k=0}^n(\alpha/\beta)^k\right)\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\beta^n\frac{(\alpha/\beta)^{n+1}-1}{(\alpha/\beta)-1}\\&=\frac1{\alpha-\beta}\left(\alpha\sum_{n=0}^\infty\alpha^n-\beta\sum_{n=0}^\infty\beta^n\right)\\&=\frac1{\alpha-\beta}\left(\frac\alpha{1-\alpha}-\frac\beta{1-\beta}\right)\\&=\frac1{(1-\alpha)(1-\beta)}.\end{align}$$
Note the RHS in the first equality: there is an $\alpha^k$, not an $\alpha^n$ like in your question and in WW1's answer.

For the case $\alpha=\beta$, see [Cauchy product of two geometric series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/371533/cauchy-product-of-two-geometric-series).